# How do I get "no" calculated with complex calculations and conditions in SQLite3

Tags: database, sqlite

If I have a table like

| no | size | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | toys |
| 2 | 23 | shelf |
| 3 | 50 | monitor |
| 4 | 62 | carrier |
| 5 | 51 | books |
| 6 | 45 | electrics |

If there is a size limit and you have to delete it from the beginning of a certain "no"

Is there any sqlite3 query to get a certain "no"?

example,

limited size : 210
I should get "no" : 2 ( id 3 + id 4 + id 5 + id 6 = 208 )

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: using version 3.31.1

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause of the `DELETE` statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t2.no >= t1.no THEN t2.size END) FROM tablename t2) > ?;
```

Change `?` to 210 or any other limit that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=42c5ea7c5525f6b6ba3438124e216faf).